# Switch case function

Tags: arduino, switch-statement

I'm using switch case function to combine different conditions and their propper functions. The problem that I faced to is that it never goes to the second case. Whatever are the switches it remains in the first case. Can anybody take a look and tell me what the error is?

thanks in advance

```
`void loop() {
  
  bool case_value = 1;

  
  while (digitalRead(BUTTON) == HIGH){
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("WAITING");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1); 
        lcd.print(" PRESS TO START");
        }    
     switch (case_value)
     {
      

    
    case 1:
      if ((digitalRead(SW1) == LOW) && (digitalRead(SW2) == LOW) && (digitalRead(SW3) == HIGH)) 
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("VERIFYING BM762");
        delay(1000);
        Check_BM762();
        case_value = 0;
        
      break;
       

    case 2:
    if ((digitalRead(SW1) == LOW) && (digitalRead(SW2) == HIGH) && (digitalRead(SW3) == LOW)) 
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("VERIFYING TR");
        delay(1000);
        Check_TR();
        case_value = 0;
        
     break;
       
      
    case 3:
      if ((digitalRead(SW1) == LOW) && (digitalRead(SW2) == HIGH) && (digitalRead(SW3) == HIGH)) 
        lcd.print("VERIFYING LEDs");
        delay(1000);
        Check_LEDs();
        case_value = 0;
        
      break;
      
    
    case 4:
      if ((digitalRead(SW1) == HIGH) && (digitalRead(SW2) == LOW) && (digitalRead(SW3) == LOW))
        lcd.print("VERIFYING BM763/807");
        delay(1000);
        Check_BM763();
        case_value = 0;
        
      break;
      
      
     
     default:
      case_value = 0;
       }
  } 
 `
```

I tried to check the synthesis if everything is OK, it has been compiled and no errors. I also tried to make it using else if function but no success.

I really appreciate if anybody can help.

Comment: with `bool case_value = 1;` `case_value` is always 1. move `bool case_value = 1;` out of the `loop` function. that will make it to preserve the value between `loop` executions. (but then `case_value` will be always set to 0)

Comment: Other than what @juraj mentioned, a `bool` data type can only have either `true`(1) or `false`(0), it can't be equal to 2, or 3, or 4 as per your code, for that, you need the data type of `byte` (arduino specific data type) or uint8_t` (commonly C++ data type).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your helpful comments. Finally I tired to do the script using two switches and it worked. I post it here maybe it can be useful for other members:

```
void init_function();
void Check_BM762();
void Check_BM763();
void Check_TR();
void Check_LEDs();
int odyssey_request(char const*HREG1);
int switch_case_value = 0;



void loop() {

  Serial.println(case_value);
  delay(500);

  if (digitalRead(BUTTON) == LOW) {
    delay(1000);
    if (digitalRead(BUTTON) == LOW) {
      Serial.println("TEST START");
      case_value = 1;

    }
    else {
      Serial.println("FAIL");
      case_value = 0;
    }
  }


  switch (case_value)
  {

    case 1:
      if (digitalRead(SW1) == LOW && digitalRead(SW2) == LOW && digitalRead(SW3) == HIGH) {
        switch_case_value = 1;
      }
      else if (digitalRead(SW1) == LOW && digitalRead(SW2) == HIGH && digitalRead(SW3) == LOW) {
        switch_case_value = 2;
      }
      else if (digitalRead(SW1) == LOW && digitalRead(SW2) == HIGH && digitalRead(SW3) == HIGH) {
        switch_case_value = 3;
      }
      else if (digitalRead(SW1) == HIGH && digitalRead(SW2) == LOW && digitalRead(SW3) == LOW) {
        switch_case_value = 4;
      }
      case_value = 0;
  }

  switch (switch_case_value)
  {
    case 1:
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("VERIFYING BM762");
      delay(1000);
      Serial.println("CASE 1 OK");
      Check_BM762();
      switch_case_value = 0;
      break;

    case 2:
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("VERIFYING TR");
      delay(1000);
      Serial.println("CASE 2 OK");
      Check_TR();
      switch_case_value = 0;
      break;

    case 3:
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("VERIFYING LEDs");
      delay(1000);
      Serial.println("CASE 3 OK");
      Check_LEDs();
      switch_case_value = 0;
      break;

    case 4:
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("VERIFYING BM763/807");
      delay(1000);
      Serial.println("CASE 4 OK");
      Check_BM763();
      switch_case_value = 0;
      break;
  }
}
```